# Create file and save it to an dynamic storage

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, jfilechooser

I create a file like this:

```java
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                     new FileOutputStream(
                      new File("C:/Users/.../Desktop/Server Recipe Log.txt"), 
                      true));
             out.println("serverText");
             out.close();
```

But I don't want to save the file on my desktop - I want to open the save as dialog to choose the place where I want to save the file.

I have tried out some tutorials with Frames but I don't want to create any frame, I want to use the native system dialog.

Comment: Actually this one doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html will help you.

Comment: *"i want to use the nativ system dialog."*  You are using the wrong language.  The closest Java offers is a `java.awt.FileDialog` or a `javax.swing.JFileChooser` using the native PLAF.

Comment: You can offer user to enter path in console but that will be too tedious and error prone.

Answer (score 2):

> ..want to use the native system dialog.

You are using the wrong language. The closest Java offers is a `java.awt.FileDialog` or a `javax.swing.JFileChooser` using the native PLAF.

### E.G.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class FileDialogs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                FileDialog fd = new FileDialog((Frame)null);
                fd.setVisible(true);
                
                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                fc.showSaveDialog(null);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JFileChooser jl = new JFileChooser();
jl.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
int save = jl.showSaveDialog(null);
if (JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION == save){
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                 new FileOutputStream(
                  new File(jl.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()+"/name.txt"), 
                  true));
         out.println("serverText");
         out.close();
}
```